# Error: Could not find or load main class. Powershell/Java

Tags: java, powershell, netbeans, terminal

I just started Java. I was initially using NetBeans to code and it works. But my teacher is insisting that we use a text editor and run it through Powershell. I'm getting a "Could not find or load main class" error with this code.

```
public class a10{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

When I run it on Netbeans, there are no errors, but I'm unable to run it on Powershell. Can someone tell me what's wrong and how I would fix it

Comment: What exactly are you typing in the shell?

Comment: i'm typing in java a10.java, I cd to the correct directory also

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are compiling the class using

`javac a10.java` and then running it by `java a10`--- Is it so

Look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748671/how-to-compile-java-sources) for more info

Comment: Hi, sorry I originally had the class as a10. I put .java hoping that might fix it. Going back to `public class a10{` did not make it work either.

Comment: a10.java is the correct source file name for a public class called a10.

Comment: First type javac a10.java -> This process is called compiling. It converts the java source code to a executable code. You can see a file a10.class created after this process. This file contains the executable code. Then run the compiled file by java a10

Comment: the command javac is not recognized. do I have to download it?

Comment: I think you do not have Java development Kit(JDK) installed. Instead you have Java Runtime environment(JRE). If it is so then you must download and install jdk. Otherwise you cannot compile and run java programs

Comment: I have Java SE Development kit 7u9

Comment: Weird, it appears to be in the JRE when I have downloaded and installed the jdk

Comment: Check this link how to use javac : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709041/javac-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20026/discussion-between-algorithms-and-user1730056)